# Saved queries on BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I had about 150 queries saved in my bigquery console for the last 2 years and all of a sudden it is empty. I saw them as recently as a couple of days back. Is this a random glitch that corrects itself? I also see a lot of queries in the query history that are not strictly mine but belong to other members in the project. This happens randomly too. Are all these common problems in BQ?

Comment: Hey Sai. Welcome to SO! If you have official Google Cloud support, I'd suggest contacting them. Bear in mind, there's currently a global issue with Google/GCP which causing problems on a lot of the services. It may be related.

Comment: Oh thanks for the pointer. It could be that too. Let me try contacting GCP support. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: You're very welcome. Feel free to post back any findings.

Comment: You were right. It was the outage. Everything looks fine in my console now.

Comment: Great to hear you're back up and running now.